# How can I set an AUTO_INCREMENT field to start with the value 6000 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

How can I set a non-auto-increment field to auto increment in MySQL? And how can I set the auto increment start value to 6000?

Answer (score 20):

> ... how set a field auto increment with start value 6000 in mysql?

If your table already exists:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 6000;
```

If you are creating your table from scratch:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table () AUTO_INCREMENT = 6000;
```

Source and further reading:

- [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html)

---

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id  int NOT NULL, 
   name     varchar(50),
   PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'Joe');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'Paul');

ALTER TABLE users MODIFY user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 6000;

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Keith');
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Steve');
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Jack');

SELECT * FROM users;
+---------+-------+
| user_id | name  |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | Bob   |
|       2 | Joe   |
|       3 | Paul  |
|    6000 | Keith |
|    6001 | Steve |
|    6002 | Jack  |
+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Great, Can we set more than one column as auto_increment in mysql or any other way to do this.. Thanks

Comment: @DanielBrunner, Try it. Insert some rows and check their values. Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 6000
```

but be aware you should have no PK lager 6000 in this table !

Comment: Great, Can we set more than one column as auto_increment in mysql or any other way to do this.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mysql will show you the correct syntax for this, and more, if you execute the following for a table that contains an auto increment PK & some data already:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE your_tablename;
```