# Set the start number for auto increment primary key

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am using MySQL db with Sails.js (Waterline).

How do I set the initial value for an "id" column in a MySQL table that start from 1000?

```
attributes: {
  id: {
    type: 'integer'
    // start from 1000
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think setting the initial auto-increment value is supported in `sails-mysql`/`waterline`. Perhaps add as issue on Github?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to

```
ALTER TABLE model AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000
```

In waterline you can run this query with the [.query()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query) method. However since this query will rebuild your entire table, it is not recommended to be run while bootstrapping your app. Depending on the size of your table it could slow down startup of your app.

Best match would be to somehow hook into the table create event and run above query once or even better: use migrations https://github.com/BlueHotDog/sails-migrations

Further reading:

- [Change auto increment starting number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number)
- [How to set an AUTO_INCREMENT field with to start with the value 6000 in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579829/how-to-set-an-auto-increment-field-with-to-start-with-the-value-6000-in-mysql)

Comment: If this query is executed on every startup won't it reset the counter everytime, and id may not be primary key (composite), also shouldn't cb() be inside callback?